# how to open a vb.application from another vb.application with parameters

Tags: vb.net

i have 2 vb applications. this is the code for the first one which when a button is clicked it will check if the other application is already open. If not, it'll open that application -

```
Dim sComputer As String
    sComputer = Environ("COMPUTERNAME")
    Dim LocalByName As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("ticket.prices", sComputer)
    If LocalByName.Length = 0 Then
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://ticket.prices.application")
    End If
```

this runs fine. but what i need is that the customerid on the application 1 that is calling application 2, should be transfered while opening app 2.
e.g -
Customer 10001 screen is open on app 1. When i click open app 2, the above code runs and opens app 2. how do i make app 2 open to customer 10001 screen. Is there any way to pass parameters while opening app 2 in System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the version of 'Process.Start' that takes 2 strings, the second being the commandline parameters. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `ProcessStartInfo` class, or use the `Start` method taking to strings.  `ProcessStartInfo` gives you a lot of options about how to start your program, which often comes in handy.  Its good to get familiar with it.

```
Dim info as New ProcessStartInfo()
info.Arguments = "10001"
info.FileName = "exename"
Dim LocalByName as New Process()
LocalByName.StartInfo = info
LocalByName.Start()
```

Getting the arguments in the new program is accomplished via `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

```
For Each arg As String In Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
    Console.WriteLine(arg)
Next arg
```

It looks like what you ultimately want to accomplish is getting the currently selected row from App 1 and passing that to the second program, though.  Is this correct?  That opens a whole new ball of wax involving interprocess communication.

EDIT: The simplest way to get the selected edit would be to write the id out to a text file.  You have to be careful when doing this because if you just write `System.IO.File.WriteAllText("selectedrow.txt", "123")`, you'll write to the app's startup path directory.  You'll want to get the exe's current path as below

```
Dim u as New Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)
dim exepath as String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(u.LocalPath)
dim fullPath as String = System.IO.Path.Combine(exepath, "selectedrow.txt")
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fullpath, "123")
```

This will overwrite the text in the file every time you change rows.  You want to wrap this in a try/catch block so as not to crash the program.  Make sure you log the errors; don't just swallow them.  To read the data, you just do

```
dim id as string = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(PathToFileYoureWritingToInTheOtherProgram)
```

in the other program.

This isn't necessarily the best way to go about things, but its the simplest way I know of off the top of my head.

You might could look at [MessageQueues](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6170794.html) if you a better solution, but as long as you're not changing selected rows every 100ms, writing the file should work fine.

Comment: Its not wrong, but it can complicate things considerably.  The simplest thing to do would be write the currently selected id out to a file whenever you change selection in your app, which can be accomplished with a single line: `System.IO.File.WriteAllText("selectedid.txt", SelectedId)`. This is slow and is a hack at IPC, but its more simple than other IPC methods.